# Using if statement inside try-catch block not working for JSoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to get my Android app to connect to the Internet and then scrape some HTML off of Amazon using JSoup. The only problem is that not all Amazon pages are the same, so I need to create several if-else statements to check different places that the data I'm looking for (such as title, images, price, etc) might be. 
The only problem is that since Android requires all code that connects to the internet to be in a try-catch statement, an unfortunate side effect is that some of if statements don't work properly. If I try to set a string to something and it doesn't find anything and sets itself to null, it's immediately kicked out of the try-catch statement which means that the rest of the code doesn't run.

Is there any way to keep the if statement running without the catch statement stopping the program?
I know this is terribly confusing, so the code is below and if you have any questions I will try to answer them in the best way that I can.
Thanks for your time!

```
public class getProductAttributes extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    String url;
    String price;
    String title;
    String imageSRC;
    ImageView productView;
    int result;

    public getProductAttributes(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }
    protected Void doInBackground (Void... voids) {

        try{
         //Create JSoup connection 
           Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            //Checks the HTML code of Amazon for the title and image, the elements are nested HTML tags that lead me to the <img> tag that I need to retrieve my data.
           Elements link= doc.select("ul.a-unordered-list.a-nostyle.a-horizontal.list.maintain-height")
                    .select("li.image.item.itemNo0.selected.maintain-height")
                    .select("span.a-list-item")
                    .select("span.a-declarative")
                    .select("div.imgTagWrapper");
            //If an image is vertical (contains a-stretch-vertical,) this code works fine because it never checks a-stretch-horizontal. If the image contains a-stretch-horizontal however, the rest of the code isn't read and the else statement doesn't do its job
            if(link.select("img.a-dynamic-image.a-stretch-vertical").equals(null)){
                link = link.select("img.a-dynamic-image.a-stetch-horizontal");

            }else{ link= link.select("img.a-dynamic-image.a-stretch-vertical");}
            //Gets Title and Image Source information from the attributes inside <img>
            title= link.attr("alt");
            imageSRC= link.attr("data-old-hires");

            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Re that series of `.select(...).select(...).select(...)`, you might look into [descendant combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators). :-)

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
if(link.select("img.a-dynamic-image.a-stretch-vertical").equals(null)){
```

makes no sense. [`select`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#select-java.lang.String-) returns an [`Elements`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) collection, which will never be `.equals(null)`. If you want to check whether the `select` returns anything, use [`isEmpty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty--) or look at the [`size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size--) of the returned collection:

```
if(link.select("img.a-dynamic-image.a-stretch-vertical").isEmpty()){
    // It's empty
```

Note that the existence of a `try/catch` has **no** influence whatsoever on the code inside it. The only thing it changes is what happens to errors thrown by that code.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. However, my code still isn't working properly. If the picture is in img.a-dynamic-image.a-stetch-horizontal, then the code inside the if-statement still isn't executed.

Comment: @coolyfrost: :-) Don't know what to tell you, if it's there and it's a descendant of the elements matched by `link`, `select` will find it.